# PHP ftp_put does'nt copy local file to remote

Tags: php, ftp

I have some files in my local and I want to copy this files to remote using FTP connection.
But I have error :

`Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\samet\cmsdemo\FTPManager.php on line 59`

codes :

```
<?php

//I defined ftp username password here but deleted for privacy

class FTPManager
{

    public function sendFilesToFtp($libraryPath, $customerName, $branch)
    {

       
            //.....rest of the code

            ftp_pasv($ftpConnection, true);

            $requiredFiles = scandir($libraryPath . "/" . $customerName . "/" . $branch);

            foreach ($requiredFiles as $file) {
                var_dump($file);
                if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
                    $localFilePath = $libraryPath . "/" . $customerName . "/" . $branch . '/' . $file;
                    $remoteFilePath = $remoteDirectory . '/' . $file;
                    if (ftp_put($ftpConnection, $remoteFilePath, $localFilePath, FTP_BINARY)) {
                        echo "File uploaded:" . $file;
                    } else {
                        echo "Error while uploading file: $file<br/>";
                    }
                }
            }

            ftp_close($ftpConnection);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I have tried allowing files, setting permissions for ftp and other ways, but for some reason I still have this problem.

Note
This application is currently running on a remote server. if I run the source code on my device, I copy my files via ftp connection. So it works in locale but not on the server

Detailed error :

remote : public_html/ds/gediz/Bornova/16.html

local : C:/cmslib/artsysdepo/gediz/Bornova/16.html

Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\samet\cmsdemo\FTPManager.php on line 59

Comment: 1) Post [mcve]. I'm sure that 80% of your code has nothing to do with your problem. 2) Post logs of any FTP client that can successfuly upload that file.

Comment: Have you debugged and checked that `$localFilePath` is correct? Does the webserver have permission to read it? Maybe that's what it can't open? What debugging have you done?

Comment: `if I run the source code on my device, I copy my files via ftp connection`...in each environment are you copying to the same FTP server? Do you have the same local folder structure too?

Comment: So your ftp connection works fine? Are you sure your webserver can read the sourcefiles? is $localFilePath readable for your webserver (often www-data for apache2)

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I have same local folder structure and copying to same ftp server.

Comment: @ErwinMoller Actually I'm trying  to copy other files in my locale. Ftp is working. But if I try to remote I cant copy. Also, my ftp server is working on same remote device.  So I'm trying to copy files from locale directory to ftp server directory. I can connecting ftp but cant copy.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to upload files from user's local machine (where the web browser runs) using a code running on your web server to a remote FTP server? + I believe you didn't really remove the right code. It's rather that you do not  need any `foreach` loop or classes to show us the problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving the `ftp_pasv` line to right after login. before doing any copying, reading, writing, nlist etc in ftp, it is necessary to put it in passive mode on many servers, i was already doing this but the location was wrong. fyi